# Save the image even the application restart

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have a problem. Everytime when I search a image from my gallery for my profilepicture its work. even when I pressed the log out button and log in again there is still my profilpicture. But when I closed the app and I restart the app then the profilepicture is gone. Does anyone know how to save the URL correctly?

```
 Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
        fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    var downUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    Constants.URL_Profil_Picture = downUrl.toString();


    setState(() {
      print('Profile Picture uploaded');
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Profile Picture Uploaded')));
    });
  }
```

```
  image: (_image != null) ? FileImage(
                              _image)
                              : NetworkImage(Constants.URL_Profil_Picture),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems the cause of the problem:

```
Constants.URL_Profil_Picture = downUrl.toString();
```

My guess it that when you restart the app, the `Constants.URL_Profil_Picture` is set to its hard-coded value again.

You'll need to store the URL somewhere that survives application restarts. The common approaches for that are:

1. Store the URL in [shared preferences](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value), or some other form of local storage. This makes the URL available only on the device where it was uploaded from.
2. Store the URL in a cloud database, such as Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database. This is the most common option, as it gives you the most flexibility.
3. Given that you're talking about user profiles: **if** you're using Firebase Authentication to sign in the user, *and* this image is their profile picture, you can also [store it in the user profile](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateProfile.html).

Comment: I woul like to do the 3rd one that would be nice. Could you show an examlpe?