# Flutter get data from firebase correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hey In my app you can edit your profile for example select a picture from your gallery for your profile picture. All work fine when I'm in the app. But when I close the app and open it again the profile picture is gone. When I select a picture from the gallery the url is stored in cloud firebase. In my code I retrieve the url from cloud firebase and want that this  Constants.URL_Profil_Picture = value.docs[0].data()['url']; is work. But it doesnt work. Does anyone know why?

```
 final FirebaseFirestore _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  getData() async {
    return await _fireStore.collection("SerX").get();
  }

  Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
        fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    var downUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    _URL = downUrl.toString();


    setState(() async {
      print('Profile Picture uploaded');
      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("SerX").doc(firebaseUser.uid).update({"url" : downUrl});

      getData().then((value){
        if(value.docs.length > 0){
          Constants.URL_Profil_Picture = value.docs[0].data()['url'];
         print(value.docs[0].data()['url']);
        }
      });
      print(Constants.URL_Profil_Picture);
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Profile Picture Uploaded')));
    });
  }
```

Comment: How does your Constants file look like?

Comment: class Constants{
  static String myName = "";
  static String URL_Profil_Picture = "";
}

Comment: How is this different from your question I answered here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030536/save-the-image-even-the-application-restart

Comment: Yes I did the 2nd point from you